# db2 ignore case in where clause

Tags: java, sql, db2

Normally we perform the ignore case as follow:

```
select * from user where UPPER(username) = UPPER('maker1');
```

Is this any way to do it in where clause condition?

I understand that we can do as follow:

```
select * from user where UPPER(username) in ( UPPER('maker1'), UPPER(maker2) );
```

But how about do it in `preparedStatement` ?

For example:

```
sb.append( "AND functionType IN (:functionType) " );
        map.put( "functionType",
                command.getListValues( command.getAllNonTradeFunctionsList( ) ) );
    query.setProperties( map );
```

Comment: You should rather insert your data (in upper case) in a temporary table and make a join on your temporary table. A request has a size limit and it is counter-productive to do so.

Answer (score -2):

what is the issue you are facing here is the simple example demonstrating your problem

```
String query = 
                "SELECT agent.familyname, agent.givenname"
                + " FROM agent"
                + " WHERE agent.agentid = ?"
                + " AND (" 
                + " familyname ilike ? OR givenname ilike ?" 
                + ") " 
                + " ORDER by familyname";


        pst.setInt(1, piececreation.agentid);
        pst.setString(2, agent_lastname.toLowerCase());
        pst.setString(3, agent_name.toLowerCase());
```

let't me know if any other help needed

Comment: How about List object to set in the parameter? my query is `in condition`.

Comment: There's no `ILIKE` predicate in Db2.